# Filtered paginated list with firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a paginated filtered list with firebase and swift (but feel free to answer with the programming language that you like the most) without filter the retrieved data on the client.

Let's suppose I've this structure

```
matches
  match-1
    name: "Match 1"
    users
        user-1: "ok"
        user-2: true
  match-2
    name: "Match 2"
    users
        user-1: "ok"
        user-2: true
        user-3: true
  match-3
    name: "Match 3"
    users
        user-1: true
        user-2: true
        user-3: true
...
```

Now I want to get a paginated list of all the matches of the user-1 that have the value "ok"

I'm doing something like this

```
matchesRef
        .queryOrdered(byChild: "users/user-1")
        .queryEqual(toValue: "ok")
        .queryStarting(atValue: "<last-fetched-user-id>")
        .queryLimited(toFirst: 5)
        .observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

});
```

But it causes a crash because "Can't call queryStartingAtValue: after queryStartingAtValue or queryEqualToValue was previously called"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you can pass in the *key* of the first item to return as a second argument to `queryStarting`. From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseQuery#-querystartingatvaluechildkey) (emphasis mine):

> `queryStartingAtValue:childKey:` is used to generate a reference to a limited view of the data at this location. The `FIRDatabaseQuery`instance returned by `queryStartingAtValue:childKey` will respond to events at nodes with a value greater than startValue, or **equal to startValue and with a key greater than or equal to childKey**.

So in code that would then be:

```
matchesRef
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "users/user-1")
    .queryStarting(atValue: "ok", childKey: "<last-fetched-user-id>")
    .queryLimited(toFirst: 5)
    .observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
```